# Не могу воспользоваться командой git clone на удаленном ftp-сервере: операция не поддерживается

Tags: git, ftp, ftp-сервер

Всем добрый день. Подключилась по фтп к удаленному серверу (с файлами своего сайта) при помощи curlftpfs. Запустила командную строку в public_html директории, в которую я примонтировала содержимое.
Хочу установить пакет с гитхаба, для этого делаю так

```
git clone https://github.com/walkor/workerman
```

Ответ на команду

```
Клонирование в «workerman»…
error: Не удалось создать «/home/мой_никнейм/ftp/мой_сайт/public_html/workerman/.git/HEAD.lock»: Неподдерживаемая операция
```

Аналогично с попыткой установить через композер:

```
composer require workerman/workerman
```

Отрывок результата:

```
- Installing workerman/workerman (v4.0.35): Extracting archive
Install of workerman/workerman failed

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.

In ZipDownloader.php line 122:
                                                                                                                                              
  Failed to extract workerman/workerman: (50) unzip -qq -o '/home/мой_никнейм/ftp/мой_сайт/public_html/vendor/composer/tmp-4ecf7c07a0210d  
  69a0bbcabaedd26cbd' -d '/home/мой_никнейм/ftp/мой_сайт/public_html/vendor/composer/c026f2a9'
```

И далее куча таких failed

Почему операция не поддерживается? Что я делаю не так? И как мне установить пакет?

Comment: 1) ftp сервер не позволяет выполнять команды 2) команда git clone не производит установку каких-либо пакетов

Comment: @user7860670
Да, я понимаю, что не производит. Неверно выразилась, мне просто нужно его скачать. Получается, мне просто клонировать его на жесткий диск, а потом копировать-вставить в директорию фтп?

Comment: Наверное так...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема скорее всего заключается в отсутствии достаточных прав на примонтированной файловой системе.
Вы можете не монтировать файловую систему при помощи curlftpfs, а соединиться с сервером по протоколу SSH. Например это можно сделать при помощи [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) в Windows или утилиты [ssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) в линуксе.

Comment: Увы, бесплатный хостинг не разрешает пользоваться ssh, поэтому пришлось клонировать на жесткий диск, а потом копировать-вставить.